# Read the 2 extent reports and create a consolidated report by merging the test results

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am running the multiple automation suites in parallel and those all are creating the different extent reports.
I want to my code to read the existing extent reports and create a consolidated one. is there any way to read the 2 extent reports and create a consolidated report by merging the test results?

I tried below code but it is not merging the test results correctly.

I am using 4.0.9 version for Extent Report.

```
   import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
   import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter;
   import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.Protocol;
   import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.Theme;

   public class ExtentReportMerger1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String file1Path = "D:\\CodeAutomation15\\ui-automation- codebase\\logs\\Reports\\ExtentReports1.html";
        String file2Path = "D:\\CodeAutomation15\\ui-automation-codebase\\logs\\Reports\\ExtentReports2.html";

        
        // Load the first report
        ExtentReports extentReports = new ExtentReports();
        ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter1 = new ExtentHtmlReporter(file1Path);
        extentReports.attachReporter(htmlReporter1);

        // Load the second report
        ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter2 = new ExtentHtmlReporter(file2Path);

        // Append the details from the second report to the first report
        extentReports.attachReporter(htmlReporter2);

        
        htmlReporter1.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
        htmlReporter1.config().setDocumentTitle("Merged Report");
        htmlReporter1.config().setEncoding("UTF-8");
        htmlReporter1.config().setProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS);
        

        // Flush the reports
        extentReports.flush();
       

        System.out.println("Merged Extent reports successfully!");
    }
}
```

I tried the above code and it appended the details from 2nd file to 1st but it was not correctly merged.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can append multiple reports in Extent `4.1.7` version of extent using json files generated by extent
If you have the .json file generated by extent Report , we can use those to create a single html report with all merged results
Below is a sample where i am running two test cases and generating the json for the extent and them I create a final html from ht generated json
For Your use case i would suggest to generate the json for every html report and then in the end you can consolidate into a single report

**Below is a sample use case to Achieve this-**

#1 First we create a common output Folder for extent json files so that we can merge them all from a common folder
#2 Them we generate two sample html Reports with there extent json files which are then written to common json folder

```
JsonFormatter json2 = new JsonFormatter(opFolder + "/Report2.json");
```

#3 Then we Create a Third extent Report , Take all the generated json files from folder and add their data into this and it will create a merged Report

```
 extentMerged.createDomainFromJsonArchive(jsonFile.getPath());
```

Full Code

```
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.JsonFormatter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class TestBase {

    public static void main(String... a) throws IOException {

        //Creating a Directory for Extent Json Output and create it if doesn't exist
        File file = new File("ExtentJson");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
        String opFolder = file.getPath();

        //Creating individual Report Number 1
        ExtentSparkReporter spark = new ExtentSparkReporter("Report1.html");
        JsonFormatter json = new JsonFormatter(opFolder + "/Report1.json");
        ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.createTest("test1").assignCategory("cat").pass("Step 1 from test 1")
            .fail("step 2 from test 1");
        extent.attachReporter(json, spark);
        extent.flush();

        //Creating individual Report Number 2
        ExtentSparkReporter spark2 = new ExtentSparkReporter("Report2.html");
        JsonFormatter json2 = new JsonFormatter(opFolder + "/Report2.json");
        ExtentReports extent2 = new ExtentReports();
        extent2.createTest("test2").assignCategory("cat").pass("Step 1 from test 2")
            .fail("step 2 from test 2");
        extent2.attachReporter(json2, spark2);
        extent2.flush();

        ExtentSparkReporter mergedSpark = new ExtentSparkReporter("spark.html");
        ExtentReports extentMerged = new ExtentReports();

        //Replace below logic to get all the .json files generated by extent in opFolder
        File jsonOPDirectory = new File("ExtentJson");
        if (jsonOPDirectory.exists()) {
            Arrays.stream(jsonOPDirectory.listFiles()).forEach(jsonFile -> {

                try {
                    extentMerged.createDomainFromJsonArchive(jsonFile.getPath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }

        extentMerged.attachReporter(mergedSpark);
        extentMerged.flush();
    }

}
```

Reference
[Combine Multiple Reports](https://www.extentreports.com/docs/versions/5/java/index.html#combine-multiple-reports)